# Are there any Laravel framework conditions that might truncate a model table during a test?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, phpunit

I've encountered a mysterious error while testing my Laravel app: a model instance that's just been created is not found inside the middleware after I call `postJson` method.

The test class `StoreEventControllerTest` extends Laravel's `TestCase`, which is using `LazilyRefreshesDatabase`. I've tried removing it form the `TestCase` and also added `RefreshDatabase`, to no avail.

I've tried debugging the test, but still couldn't figure out what's going on:

### Test debugging step #1: A model instance's been created

[image: Test debugging step #1: A model instance's been created]

### Test debugging step #2: The recently created model is not found!

[image: Test debugging step #2: The recently created model is not found!]

Route is configured in `routes/api.php`:

```php
Route::post('stores/{key}/receive-payload', StoreEventController::class)
    ->middleware('event.signature')
    ->name('stores.receive-payload');
```

The middleware `event.signature` `handle` method:

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $key = $request->route('key');
    $sourceName = $request->get('source');

    if (!$key || !$sourceName) {
        abort(401);
    }

    /** @var EventStore $store */
    if (!$store = EventStore::find($key)) {
        abort(401);
    }

    /** @var EventStoreSource $source */
    if (!$source = $store->sources()->where('name', $sourceName)->first()) {
        abort(401);
    }

    $providedSignature = $this->getProvidedSignature($request, $source);

    if (!$providedSignature) {
        abort(401);
    }

    if (!$this->checkSignature($providedSignature, $request, $store, $source)) {
        abort(401);
    }

    // Bind the event store to the request so that it can be used in the controller
    app()->instance(EventStoreSource::class, $source);

    return $next($request);
}
```

And here is a relevant excerpt from model `EventStore`:

```php
use App\Models\Concerns\UsesUuidKey;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class EventStore extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    use UsesUuidKey;
```

```php
namespace App\Models\Concerns;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

trait UsesUuidKey
{
    public function initializeUsesUuidKey()
    {
        $this->setKeyType('string');

        $this->setIncrementing(false);
    }

    public static function bootUsesUuidKey()
    {
        static::creating(fn ($model) => $model->setUuidKey());
    }

    protected function setUuidKey()
    {
        $keyName = $this->getKeyName();

        if (blank($this->getAttribute($keyName))) {
            $this->setAttribute($keyName, Str::uuid());
        }
    }
}
```

The table `event_stores` structure:

```sql
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id           | varchar(191)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| team_id      | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| name         | varchar(191)        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| secret       | text                | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| created_at   | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| updated_at   | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| activated_at | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| config       | json                | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sources      | json                | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Here's some extra commands I ran on the debug console during the test, which demonstrate the database connection doesn't change during the whole process:
[image]

Edit: I've added the table description.
Edit 2: Added a screenshot of the debug console after running commands to print the DB connection name.

Comment: It looks like you're looking it up by the UUID, but `find()` will search for the `id` if you haven't specified the primary key.

Comment: @aynber the table primary key's name is `id`. I added the table structure description to the question.

Comment: What you are trying to do with the middleware (provide a EventStoreSource) based on some params is what laravel uses ServiceProviders for: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/providers, RefreshDatabases also truncates the tables, but that should happen after the testcase, not during

Comment: I think your issue may be related to the DB connection... can you check what database connection is the default on your test and when you are on the controller? Maybe, somehow, the code is changing what default database connection or a value from it, so it is reading another database, hence empty

Comment: @matiaslauriti I'm going to try that out. I have a feeling that's what's going on, but no clue why, though.